# Bottom Navigation Icon color change

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am using a BottomNavigation [this](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) when i try to change bottom navigation icon colors with black background its not change color.

```
 bottomNavigation.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE4770A"));
 bottomNavigation.setInactiveColor(Color.WHITE);
 bottomNavigation.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

But when i tried it with background it changes icon color.

```
 bottomNavigation.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE4770A"));
 bottomNavigation.setInactiveColor(Color.WHITE);
```

How do fix it? it changes icon color with color background.

Comment: try using `setDefaultBackgroundColor()` instead of `setBackgroundColor()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [ahbottomnavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) repo, `setBackgroundColor()` will override the accent colors for icons.

Replace `setBackgroundColor()` with `setDefaultBackgroundColor()` :

```
 bottomNavigation.setDefaultBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 4):

I have an another solution, if you wanna try in XML,

> app:itemBackground="@color/white" --> This can be use to bottom bar color
>    app:itemIconTint="@color/blue" --> This can be used to change icons color
>    app:itemTextColor="@color/blue" --> This can be used to change icon bottom text color

XML source code shown as below

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/blue" 
        app:itemTextColor="@color/blue" 
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Ref :pic
[image]

Comment: app:itemIconTint="@color/blue" this worked thank you so much :)