# Different color for each menu item

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I want to create a bottom navigation bar with different color for different menu items. Something similar to "https://github.com/gauravk95/bubble-navigation".

All I could do till now is just change the on selected and on unselected colors for the navbar. Is there any way I can change these colors for each menu item?

Comment: Check out the following answer and tell me if it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639296/bottom-navigation-icon-color-change?rq=1

Comment: That changes icon color for all the menu items of the navbar. I want to change the individual icon color